# How can I tile a background page to meet my printed page in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-office, printing, microsoft-visio, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-visio-2013

Can I set a background page up, such that a logo is displayed in the top right hand corner of each *printed* page, and the title of the page is displayed at the bottom left hand corner?

Ideally, it would also print the *printed* page number for the page (ie. If my "Diagram1" page has 6 printed pages, it would show how to put them together off the printer), but I've resigned that to being a manual process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think either are possible via background pages or even foreground pages if the actual **printed** pages differ from the pages as you see them in Visio.

Comment: Yep, that's what I suspected. Visio: great for drawings that *stay on the screen*.